# Duplication warning for dplyr joins in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I use `dplyr::left_join()` an awful lot and I sometimes fail to notice when duplicate records in the second table result in multiple matches (and a main table with more rows than I started with).

I’d love to know if there’s a way for R to throw up a warning message when this happens. Or am I just being lazy? Should I take more care to ensure I’m not working with tables with duplicate records?

Comment: The data.table version gives a warning when doing a full_join. But I think you should always check for duplicates manually before joining two tables, unless you know that you are performing a one-many join. And always check that the output matches your expectations. It's common sense. If doing a one-one join programmatically, I'd strongly advise that you add a check for duplicates prior to the join, giving a warning if duplicates exist. Just my 2 cents. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to use your own version of `left_join`, where you compare the number of rows:

```
my_left_join <- function(x, y, ...){
  res <- dplyr::left_join(x, y, ...)

  if (nrow(res) > nrow(x)) warning("Duplicated records found")
  return(res)  
}
```

This way `my_left_join` throws a warning:

```
a <- tibble(id = 1:3)
b <- tibble(id = c(1:3, 1), val = 7:10)


a %>% dplyr::left_join(b, by = "id")
a %>% my_left_join(b, by = "id")
```

Comment: +1 upvote. I think many R users don't take advantage of the fact that you can write your own functions, unlike other commercial software.

Comment: Ooh thank you. That’s quite a simple solution. I’ll try it out today on a script I’m working on 

Comment: @Edward I agree. I’m guilty of that myself. I don’t make as much use of user defined functions as I could.

Comment: Works perfectly and I've even modified it to use beepr:beep() to make a noise at the same time (because it's easy to miss the warnings when you're running a huge script and the console output is scrolling v fast)